# Add arguments using kwargs in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python, ipython

Below is my function

```
def list_abc(self, name, id, keywords):
        cmd = ABC() //ABC is a class
        cmd.id=id
        cmd.name=name
        cmd.keywords=keywords
        return ABC(cmd)
```

I wish to pass `name`, `id` and '`keywords` using **kwargs in Python.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass \*\*kwargs argument to another function with \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867562/pass-kwargs-argument-to-another-function-with-kwargs)

Answer (score 7):

```
kwargs = {'name': 'Frank', 'id': 999, 'keywords': ['cool', 'smart']}
result = self.list_abc(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def list_abc(self, **kwargs):
    # check if 'name' in kwargs, etc
    cmd = ABC()
    cmd.id = kwargs['id']
    cmd.name = kwargs['name']
    cmd.keywords = kwargs['keywords']
    return ABC(cmd) # not sure what ABC(ABC) does

...
some_instance.list_abc(name='name', id=1, keywords=['good', 'luck'])


# or, if have a dictionary containing name, id and keywords, you can pass it to the
# method as follows
data = {'name':'name', 'id':1, 'keywords':('a', 'b')}
some_instance.list_abc(**data)
```

Comment: `[setattr(cmd, k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()]`

Comment: @DrTyrsa, no need to create a new list.

Comment: @khachik It isn't assigned to any variable, so it's destroyed on the next line. It's just a short form of `for` cycle. Faster and less error-prone than assigning attrs by hand.

Comment: @DrTyrsa: I think if you're calling a function for its side effects, it's preferable to make an explicit for loop. It's cleaner to read, and it avoids assigning memory for the list (even if you don't assign it to anything, Python will still create the list and then throw it away).

Comment: @ThomasK I don't think that for-loop is clener to read. And can you, please, explain me the disadvantages of assigning memory to the object and throwing it away on the second line (in this situation)? I thing we are not in 80's (and even in 80's it wouldn't be a problem).

Comment: @DrTyrsa: In this case, it's unlikely to make much difference. With a large number of items obviously it wastes memory. I prefer to get into good habits with things like this, especially when giving examples for others. Oh, and if you do it on one line, the explicit for loop is one character shorter.

Comment: @ThomasK If you have a class with number of attributes that "wastes memory" you are definetely doing something wrong.