# pass **kwargs argument to another function with **kwargs

Tags: python

I do not understand the following example, let's say I have these functions:

```
# python likes
def save(filename, data, **kwargs):
    fo = openX(filename, "w", **kwargs) # <- #1
    fo.write(data)
    fo.close()
# python doesnt like
def save2(filename, data, **kwargs):
    fo = openX(filename, "w", kwargs) # <- #2
    fo.write(data)
    fo.close()

def openX(filename, mode, **kwargs):
    #doing something fancy and returning a file object
```

Why is #1 the right solution and #2 the wrong one? `**kwargs` is basically a dict, so if I want to pass down the argument to openX I think the correct way would be without `**` and just giving the dict. But Python obviously doesn't like the second one and tells me I gave 3 instead of 2 arguments.

So what's the reason behind this?

Comment: I wonder why you call it `**args` in the code. This is possibly the worst possible name as people will confuse it with `*args`

Comment: Well I never really use *args, so I use **args^^, but well I can modify it.

Comment: the variable names are for human readability to the compiler the name used is not important. Arguments have Ordinality, that the compiler will reject with Syntax error. 

```def A(B:int,C:int=1,*D,**E)``` # Is valid Syntax. Argument types are in order: no defaults, then defaults, then * arg, then ** arg  !!  (now some error examples) :
```def A(B:int,C:int=1,**E,*D)``` # Syntax Error. argument D before E // 
```def A(C:int=1,B:int)``` # Syntax Error. argument B must be first // 
```def A(B:int,C:int=1,*D,**E,**F)``` Sytax Error. cannot have two `**` arguments

Answer (score 257, accepted):

In the second example you provide 3 arguments: filename, mode and a dictionary (`kwargs`). But Python expects: 2 formal arguments plus keyword arguments.

By prefixing the dictionary by '**' you unpack the dictionary `kwargs` to keywords arguments.

A dictionary (type `dict`) is a single variable containing key-value pairs.

"Keyword arguments" are key-value method-parameters.

Any dictionary can by unpacked to keyword arguments by prefixing it with `**` during function call.

Comment: now I get it. I thought keywords and dict were the same thing.

Comment: "Any dictionary can by expanded to keywords by prefixing it with ** during function call." <- thats cool

Comment: See also: Python docs on [keyword parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) and [unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: An actual code example would make this answer considerably clearer.

Answer (score 34):

Expanding on @gecco 's answer, the following is an example that'll show you the difference:

```py
def foo(**kwargs):
    for entry in kwargs.items():
        print("Key: {}, value: {}".format(entry[0], entry[1]))

# call using normal keys:
foo(a=1, b=2, c=3)
# call using an unpacked dictionary:
foo(**{"a": 1, "b":2, "c":3})

# call using a dictionary fails because the function will think you are
# giving it a positional argument
foo({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3})
# this yields the same error as any other positional argument
foo(3)
foo("string")
```

Here you can see how unpacking a dictionary works, and why sending an actual dictionary fails

Answer (score 16):

The `**` syntax tells Python to collect keyword arguments into a dictionary. The `save2` is passing it down as a non-keyword argument (a dictionary object). The `openX` is not seeing any keyword arguments so the `**args` doesn't get used. It's instead getting a third non-keyword argument (the dictionary). To fix that change the definition of the `openX` function.

```
def openX(filename, mode, kwargs):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you, but I also want to use openX without save, so I have to stick with the keywords. I thought passing down keywords was basically the same as passing down a dict, but I didn't know until now :)

Comment: @xMRW They can't be the same thing since you can pass a dictionary as a parameter to any function as well. Your #1 is the right one then.

Answer (score 4):

The following code use `kwargs` and transfer it to another function:

```
def myprint( kwargs ):
    # default values
    a = kwargs.get('a', None)
    b = kwargs.get('b', None)

    # print both
    print('a={}, b={}'.format(a,b))

def mytest( **kwargs ):
    myprint( kwargs )

mytest()
mytest(b=2)
```

yields:

```
a=None, b=None
a=None, b=2
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about _why_ a particular piece of code works, not how to pass arguments.

Answer (score 2):

For #2
args will be only a formal parameter with dict value, but not a keyword type parameter.

If you want to pass a keyword type parameter into a keyword argument
You need to specific ** before your dictionary, which means  **args

check this out for more detail on using **kw

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: So there is a big difference between **kwargs and dict?

Comment: thank you, I always like to read more about topics i don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Because a dictionary is a single value. You need to use keyword expansion if you want to pass it as a group of keyword arguments.

Comment: sorry but what is a "keyword expansion"? do you mean I should use dict_var instead of **args and just using def func(argument, dict_var=0)...func(1,{1:"a",2:"b"})