# IPython can't draw 3D scatter plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

When I try to draw a 3D scatter plot [per the instructions here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), I get the following error:

```
In [10]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 176, in __draw_idle_agg
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 474, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1159, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 271, in draw
    for col in self.collections]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 455, in do_3d_projection
    xs, ys, zs = self._offsets3d
AttributeError: 'Path3DCollection' object has no attribute '_offsets3d'

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True
```

Previously I got this error when using PyQt4. I spent several hours installing PyQt5 (difficult on my version of Ubuntu). Having now started ipython with

```
ipython --pylab='qt5'
```

I expected it would work, but again got the same error message when trying to plot.

Note that it happens when I call the `scatter` method. Then, until I close the figure, it continues to give the same backtrace every time I hit enter in ipython.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D` and `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')`? (It would be helpful if you showed all the commands leading up to the error.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the problem. [I was passing some keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867562/pass-kwargs-argument-to-another-function-with-kwargs) to `scatter()` without the `**`.

Argh.