# __init__(self, grammar, **options) and I pass (grammar_string,myoptdict): TypeError: 2 args, 3 given

Tags: python, dictionary, python-plyplus

I am using plyplus and just trying to get the **debug** option turned on.

The `Grammar` class is defined like:

```
class Grammar(object):
    def __init__(self, grammar, **options)
```

and I am invoking it via

```
options = { 'debug' : True }
Grammar(long_string, options)
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 argument (3 given)
```

I am going mad looking at this; what's wrong? This is using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu and I verified that there is no older version of **plyplus** on the system with one fewer argument.

Comment: You are passing `options` as a single argument: a dictionary.  What you should be doing is passing the items of the dictionary as keyword arguments.  To do that, use `**options`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867562/pass-kwargs-argument-to-another-function-with-kwargs

Answer (score 0):

Zondo's answer worked for me:

Grammar(mylongstring, **options)

I've been using Python for some years but never came across this before.

Thanks!