# Class __init__ with mix of fixed and variable length **kwargs arguments

Tags: python

I have a class with two must have arguments and I would like to supply it with a dictionary of optional arguments. I have seen a similar style of class definitions in tensorflow [optimizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam). A minimal example looks like this:

```
class Dataset:
    def __init__(self, source, target, **kwargs):
        self.source = source
        self.target = target
        self.shuffle = kwargs['shuffle']
        
    def shuffle(self):
        return self
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    source = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    targets = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    
    kwargs = {
        'shuffle' : False,
        'shift' : 10
    }
    
    trainset = Dataset(source, targets, kwargs)
```

and it produces an error:

```
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    trainset = Dataset(source, targets, *kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

In addition to helping me to fix the error I would appreciate a comment on whenever this type of class definition with mix of fixed and variable arguments is not a best practice.

**Solution**: Following a comment and a reply, solution was to use `Dataset(source, targets, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Prefix a dictionary with `**` to unpack it as keyword arguments to a function - `Dataset(source, targets, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass **kwargs to the constructor it will work, you need to unpack the dict elements into the functions. See also [pass **kwargs argument to another function with **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867562/pass-kwargs-argument-to-another-function-with-kwargs)